# Dynamically loading data according to a session attribute

Tags: session, jpa, cdi

I'm trying to dynamically load dataSet accordingly to an user session attribute, which I inject and set it as a parameter in a namedQuery.

The namedQuery works fine, but I'm not getting the dataSet as desired.

I mean, when the session attribute is 9882, the dataSet loaded corresponds to the findAll query. But, in the meantime, if another user logs in the app - and his session attribute is 4207 - the dataSet stills the same as 9882, which means that the dataSet still correspond to the findAll query; and vice-versa: if the 1st session attribute is 4207, it uses the findByPrefDep query, as expected, but the dataSet still the same for a 9882 session attribute logged after that 4207 user.

```
@Inject
private String SessionPrefDep;

public Collection<T> getItems() {
  if (items == null) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(SessionPrefDep) == 4207) {
      items = this.ejbFacade.findByPrefDep();
        } else if (Integer.valueOf(SessionPrefDep) == 9882) {
            items = this.ejbFacade.findAll();
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Does anyone knows how can I achieve the desired control?

Thanks in advance.

----------- new section

The Producer:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BeanCDI {

private final String sessionPrefDep = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("xPrefDep");

@Produces
public String SessionPrefDep() {
    return sessionPrefDep;
  }
}
```

The Controller:

```
@Inject
private Instance<String> SessionPrefDep;

public Collection<T> getItems() {

    int sessionId = Integer.valueOf(SessionPrefDep.get());

    if ((items == null) && (sessionId == 4207)) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findByPrefDep();
        System.out.print("****************** findByPrefDep() - sessionId:" + sessionId);
    } else if ((items == null) && (sessionId == 9882)) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findAll();
        System.out.print("****************** findAll() - sessionId:" + sessionId);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching about CDI, I found a very good book covering what I needed to resolve my problem. The book, which I recommend, is Apress Beginning EJB.3.2nd Edition May2013, and the solution I found in chapter 10.

The only thing I had to change was the CDI scope in my Producer. Doing so, the problem was resolved:

```
//@ApplicationScoped --> I was wrongly, for my needs, using this scope...
@RequestScoped
public class BeanCDI {

private final String sessionPrefDep = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("xPrefDep");

@Produces
public String SessionPrefDep() {
return sessionPrefDep;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via

```
@Inject
private Instance<String> SessionPrefDed;

//then in your code
int sesionId = Integer.valueOf(SessionPrepDef.get());
```

This way you should always get a fresh value. But it also depends how do you create this object, as far as I remember you can inject strings in CDI only with producers.

Comment: Hi Petr Mensik! I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Petr Mensik, I've tested but, unfortunately, it didn't work. The session id continues to be the same accordingly to the first user that logs in the app. It stills in the memory of Glassfish. I've updated the code to show the Producer and the injected parameter as you told me. Please, see if I'm making a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Petr Mensik, I've found the solution (see my answer above). But, anyway, thanks for your help!